# Why this NumberFormatException?

Tags: java

I have this stack trace (part of)

```
Servlet.service() for servlet action threw exception
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "37648"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
 at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:403)
 at java.lang.Long.valueOf(Long.java:482)
 at java.lang.Long.decode(Long.java:593)
```

in one of my logfile
I don't know what was real input string.
But the user had made happen the same stack trace.

How such a stacktrace can happen?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Probably because they have a leading zero in their input.

This runs fine:

```
public class DecodeLong
{
    public static final void main(String[] params)
    {
        long    l;

        l = Long.decode("37648");
        System.out.println("l = " + l);
    }
}
```

But if you change this:

```
l = Long.decode("37648");
```

to this:

```
l = Long.decode("037648");
```

...it becomes invalid octal, and the exception from `Long.parseLong` **doesn't include the leading zero**:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "37648"
        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Long.valueOf(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Long.decode(Unknown Source)
        at DecodeLong.main(DecodeLong.java:24)
```

It doesn't include it because `decode` calls `parseLong` without the zero, but with the base set to 8.

Talk about obscure. :-) So if you update your program to handle the exception by showing the *actual* input, you'll probably find it's something along those lines.